# Is it possible to see few last post of facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, xml-parsing

i want to write an app, which shows the combined view of twitter and Facebook.
i got the twit but don't get any thing about Facebook. 
so i want to know that is it possible to see few last post of Facebook in android.

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, you need to ask for `read_stream` permission.

Refer this -> [Read Stream Permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/)